# Terminal and Vim

Tags: terminal, vim

I open a terminal then I open Vim. Then I work on my source code, but unfortunately I click on the close button of the terminal title bar and my work is lost. Is it possible to configure Vim such that it will tell me when I am trying to close the terminal without saving my work?

Thanks!

Comment: gnome-terminal will warn if there is any program running in the terminal windows including, of course, vim.

Comment: Which "Termimal"? There's a program called that on many different OSes, and they have different ways of being configured to cope with this problem.

Comment: @Warren Young: It is a xfce4-terminal. According to the answer of Chris Down below, I would like to change the way my terminal handles WM_DELETE_WINDOW, but I do not know how to do it yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no way for `vim` to know in advance that it's grandparent process (the terminal) is killed so it too, is normally killed as a result of killing the parent processes.

However, on most default setups `vim` will create a `.swp` file named after the current file being edited; for instance `MyPrecious.java.swp`. This file should contain a snapshot of the file `MyPrecious.java` just before the `vim` process was killed. Unless you have set up `vim` to specifically put these `.swp` files in some other directory, they should reside in the same directory as the edited file and you can easily restore your editing work.

Note that some of these files starts with a dot `.` so they are invisible unless you use `ls -a` to list the files in a directory.

Comment: +1 but you should add that the `.swp` filename starts with a `.` so it is by default 'invisible'.

Answer (score 12):

Looking at the problem from a different angle, `screen` or `tmux` will allow you to keep your shell going independently of your terminal. When you close the terminal you can open a new one and reconnect to the original shell. Vim will still be running.

Comment: I use tmux and have it hooked into [`.zlogin`](https://github.com/mscharley/dotfiles/blob/master/zlogin) so it's always started up when I login to a shell. Never lost a window since.

Comment: @MatthewScharley - `if` just takes return values -- you don't need to do your roundabout issuing of `tmux` followed by checking `$?`, just check `tmux`.

Answer (score 7):

`vim` has no control over how your terminal's GUI handles `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`. Instead, look for a setting in your terminal that controls how the terminal acts when asked to close when it has a shell with children.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I change the way my terminal (xfce4-terminal) handles WM_DELETE_WINDOW?

Answer (score 5):

There **is** a way for Vim to know that the terminal has been closed:  the `SIGHUP` signal.

When you close a terminal, the [`SIGHUP` signal is sent](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_10) to the [controlling process](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_114), which is usually your shell.  Your shell should then exit, [causing Vim to be sent the `SIGHUP` signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html#tag_16_01_03_01).  By default, processes simply [terminate when they receive the `SIGHUP` signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html).

I'm not familiar with Vim, but maybe it can be configured to save all work before exiting when a `SIGHUP` signal is received.  If not, maybe you can set a [shell `trap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap) on `SIGHUP`, perhaps in combination with running Vim with [`nohup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nohup.html), to execute a special command that somehow causes Vim to exit more gracefully when the terminal is closed.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, vim cannot react to such an event. But you might consider one of these work-arounds:

- Using `gvim` instead of `vim`, which can be invoked from the command line, too. An alias might help adjusting to the switch (assuming bash-compatible shell): `alias vim=gvim`. Stating gvim as your preferred editor might help, too: `export EDITOR=gvim`. This works only on a local machine, though.
- Using a terminal muxer (such as `tmux` or `screen`) was already mentioned.
- Configuring your terminal (whichever that is) to confirm that you want to close it. This will catch you by surprise the first few times, which should force you to think before closing your terminal in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

This came to me after I asked the question in another forum [AskUbuntu: vim.desktop - changes lost when terminal exits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761426/vim-desktop-changes-lost-when-terminal-exits) and a lot of experimental `*.desktop` files demonstrating that `gnome-terminal` would allow `vim` to be killed without warning even if it was running in an shell & even if there were other commands before or after it for `bash` or `gnome-terminal` to run.

An "interactive" shell (`bash -i`) sounded sure to invoke the GNOME warning upon closing the window, based on the literal warning message:

> *Close this terminal?* There is still a process running in this terminal. Closing the terminal will kill it.

but adding the `-i` option to bash, as run from the `*.desktop` file, stopped GNOME from opening a window in my testing (with Ubuntu 16.04 - `gnome-terminal` 3.18.3).  So instead I tried invoking the interactive shell from a wrapper script, and that was a full solution:

`/usr/local/bin/vim-gnome-wrap`

```
#!/bin/bash -f
bash -ic 'vim "$@"' vim "$@"
```

... then edit `/usr/share/applications/vim.desktop` or copy it to a new `*.desktop` file, with these changes:

```
TryExec=vim-gnome-wrap
# It doesn't open window for interactive shell when GNOME arranges the terminal:
# Terminal=true
# Exec=vim-gnome-wrap %F
# ... yet it does so when gnome-terminal is run explicitly:
Terminal=false
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "vim-gnome-wrap %F"
```

This provides a warning upon closing the window whether the `vim` buffer has unsaved changes or not, and works on multiple files.  Special thanks to @muru below for suggesting `$@` syntax which preserves arguments exactly (spaces & metacharacters).

Comment: In a script, I'd use `bash -ic 'vim "$@"' vim "$@"`. That should handle filenames with spaces, etc. well enough. (The second `vim` is just `$0` for the command, it can be anything.)

Comment: thanks @muru, have edited as such, noticed problem this eve & hoped there would be a quick answer like that.